# Sending Windows commands through RDP Connection Manager

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop

Given the Windows Server 2012 charms disconnecting from a server seems difficult outside full screen. Win + C is required to disconnect from the UI.

Can one assign a special key to real-time delegate recipient of windows commands - or must that depend on the application full screen?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows key combinations it's a setting under Local Resources. By default they are sent to the remote computer only when using the full screen.

For session commands in an RDP session Ctrl-Alt-End brings up the same menu as Ctrl-Alt-Delete.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to set it in an rdp file:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393668(v=ws.10).aspx

```
keyboardhook:i:<value>
```

Determines how Windows key combinations are applied when you are connected to a remote computer.

- 0 – Windows key combinations are applied on the local computer.
- 1 – Windows key combinations are applied on the remote computer.
- 2 – Windows key combinations are applied in full-screen mode only.